# Trying to install driver for TP Link TL-WN822N v4, make command fails

Tags: drivers, wireless, compiling, make, tp-link

I have been trying to install a driver for my TP Link TL-WN822N v4 Wireless card. Following the instructions from [this repository for rtl1819eu driver](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver), I ran `make` and then `sudo make install` and this came up:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/build M=/home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
modules make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic'
CC [M] /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o 
In file included from /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/drv_types.h:32:0, from /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22: /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service.h: 
In function ‘thread_enter’: /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service.h:342:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration] allow_signal(SIGTERM); ^~~~~~~~~~~~ do_signal /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service.h: 
In function ‘flush_signals_thread’: /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service.h:352:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration] if (signal_pending (current)) ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ timer_pending /home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service.h:354:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration] flush_signals(current); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ do_signal 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors 
scripts/Makefile.build:302: recipe for target '/home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed 
make[2]: * [/home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1 
Makefile:1546: recipe for target '_module_/home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver' failed 
make[1]: * [_module_/home/rick/rtl8192eu-linux-driver] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic' 
Makefile:1335: recipe for target 'modules' failed make: * [modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try a different repository. From the terminal:

```
cd ~
rm -rf rtl8192eu-linux-driver
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Your wireless should now be working